# psql start multiple concurrent .sql scripts and limit processes

Tags: postgresql, powershell, psql

Background: 
OS Win10
postgresql 9.6 
postgis 2.5

Story: 
I have 200 .slq scripts with postgres (st_union function) queries in a win folder.
I can run a "for %%f in (*.sql) do (start cmd /c "psql -U postgres -f "%%f" abn2030")" .bat on these files in parallel and  my 8 cores have some fodder. 
EXCEPT 200 script are too many. I am looking for a way to limit the running 'cmd'/'psql' instances. I want to check for instances of cmd (or psql) running and start the next (waiting in line) .sql scripts only if number of instances of cmd/psql is under 15. (if this makes sense; maybe there are other options).
I tried powershell and python (to a lesser extend) and I don't know with which (if any of these) to proceed.

powershell: 
running directly. script executes with no problems.

```
cmd /c ""C:\PostgreSQL\9.6\bin\psql.exe" -U postgres -d db -f "D:\Dropbox\scripts_sql\execute_htunion\pwshl\queries1.SQL""
```

in script: (stolen mostly from another post)

```
function numInstances([string]$process)
{
@(get-process -ea silentlycontinue $process).count
}

$files = Get-ChildItem $scriptDir\*.sql

foreach ($file in $files) {
$running = numInstances("cmd")
if ($running.Count -le 2) {
$script= {& cmd /c psql "-U postgres -f $file db"}
    Start-Job $script
         write-host "$file"
} else {
     $running | Wait-Job
}
Get-Job | Receive-Job
}
```

output: psql: FATAL:  role " postgres -f D:\Dropbox\scripts_sql\execute_htunion\pwshl\queri" does not exist

How can I send the start .sql in psql command in powershell (or in other languages)?

EDIT:
Solved in .bat with:
"C:\Program Files\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login -i -c "find . -iname '*.sql' -print0 | xargs --null --max-procs=14 -I {} psql.exe -U postgres -d db -f {}"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Git for Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases) should have [xargs](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html) and [find](https://linux.die.net/man/1/find), which are Linux-originating commands that in tandem are ideal for the task:

```
find . -name '*.sql' -print0 \
| xargs --null --max-procs=16 -I{} psql.exe -U postgres -d db -f {}
```